# Separate a dataframe into smaller dataframes with R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a large set of data that is essentially the following

```
name  age  class       sex    hair_color
John  23   senior      M      brown
Emily 20   sophomore   F      black
```

What I would like to do is look at the seniors and sophomores and other classes (juniors and freshman) separately. How do I take my dataframe and split it into four smaller dataframes?

I thought I could condition my dataframe as follows, but having trouble with syntax

```
sen<-df[,] where df[,3]=="senior"
```

is what I am trying to get to.

It turns out, I was almost there. The following is correct:

```
sen<-df[(df$class=='senior'),]
```

You can also do it with subset:

```
subset(df,df$class=='senior',select=c(name,age,sex,hair_color)
```

Comment: Check the function `subset` from base R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct R syntax would be:

Option 1:

```
Sen_df <- df[df$class %in% "senior", ]
```

Option 2:

```
library(dplyr)
Sen_df <- filter(df, class == "senior")
```